# Create Target Platform for Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am in the progress of creating some plug-ins that hook into the Eclipse IDE. However I'm stuck on creating a reproducible target platform.

My naïve first approach was to check the about dialog of a fresh instance of Eclipse for the used features (it's only one) and create a target platform based on these:

```xml
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit"> 
    <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars"/>
    <unit id="epp.package.java" version="0.0.0"/>
</location>
```

(I also tried `org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group`, which from the dialog seems to be the same thing.)

Needless to say: this does not work at all. Using the planner mode (which I rather not, because "reproducible") allows for me to at least start some sort of Eclipse application, but it looks different and all the Java stuff (perspective, views, menu contributions) is missing.

I checked the Eclipse Git repository, but they don't seem to use target platforms at all, so... what is the correct way to get a target platform containing the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually resort to the Eclipse Platform p2 repository to assemble a target platform for IDE development. It contains everything you need if your plug-ins extend the Platform, JDT and/or PDE (i.e. you don't extend maven tools or the like).

For each Eclipse version there is a distinct repository

- Luna: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4
- Mars: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5
- Neon Milestones: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6milestones

Therein is a feature called *Eclipse SDK* (id `org.eclipse.sdk.ide`). It contains the platform plus JDT and PDE. If I understood your question this is what you are looking for.

The repository also contains a feature called *Eclipse Platform SDK* which contains only the platform (i.e. the workbench) but not JDT and PDE.

If you don't need (or don't want) PDE to be part of the target platform you should be able to select the *Eclipse Platform SDK* and the *Eclipse Java Development Tools* feature.

For examples, you may want to look at this projects target definitions:
https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/com.codeaffine.extras.target/eclipse-4.4.target

You probably already know that there is a also an [*Orbit* repository](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/) which contains libraries used by Eclipse projects, packaged as OSGi bundles.